# Opening Linux Subsystem for Windows shell from Eclipse Photon (IDE)

Tags: command-line, bash, eclipse, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ide

## Background

I am running Eclipse Photon as my primary IDE for writing Java code.  Eclipse has a *terminal* view that opens up a windows command line inside the application

[image: Terminal View]

I assume this is simply executing `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` inside a window in the application.  I am using Windows 10 and have enabled Linux Subsystem for Windows.

## Question

Does anyone know if this is a location value (IE: where it points to the cmd.exe file) configuration somewhere in the eclipse directory structure?  When you enable the Linux Subsystem it creates a bash.exe file in the same directory.  So I would essentially like to replace the `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` string with `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

After digging into this a bit deeper on the [Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/210/) there is a configuration specifically for this.

1. Navigate to Windows -> Preferences -> Terminal -> Local Terminal
2. Add the following entry

   **name**: WSL Bash

   **path**: C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe

   *or use C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe*
3. Then, on any file, right click -> show in... -> WLS Bash

[image]